# Custom UIView starts off covering only a portion of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, ios-simulator

I have a strange problem.  I have a custom UIView that is supposed to fill the screen.  Here is a picture of the GUI along with the constraints:

[image: GUI Image]

Now the main problem is, on the iPad Pro 12.9" simulator, at first the custom view only fills a portion of the screen- like it was following the Air 2 size constraints.  However, if I go away from the screen and come back to it such that the screen isn't recreated but just redisplayed, the gui looks almost perfect.  On the other hand, the gui looks almost perfect on the iPad Mini device that I have, without having to go and come back.  It isn't quite there because the image in the middle section gets clipped slightly at the top and bottom, but I haven't tried hard to figure out why that is happening.  I have spent a fair amount of time trying to debug the problem I am asking about.  If you need more information to help me solve this problem, I'm happy to provide it- just specify what you need.  On the view controllers that actually hold this custom view, I use autoresizing masks to have it fill the screen, which apparently isn't working, but constraints have been tried and they didn't help either.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

UPDATE: I changed the constraints to something I liked better, as I had used "Reset to Suggested Constraints" and that created some weird constraints.  Problem still exists, however.

[image: Current Constraints]

Here is some of the code involving the view:

```
class SessionDisplayViewController: SessionViewDisplayViewControllerBase
{
//some code omitted for succinctness
@IBOutlet weak var mySessionView: SessionDisplayView!

override func getSessionView() -> SessionDisplayView
{
    return mySessionView
}
...
}

class SessionViewDisplayViewControllerBase: UIViewController, SessionDisplayViewDelegate{

...
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
...
 if !ShareData.sharedInstance.sessionDataObjectContainer.keys.contains(curSessName) || ShareData.sharedInstance.sessionDataObjectContainer[curSessName] == nil
    {
        setupMySession(isLive: false, isFinalized: false)
    }
    else if (ShareData.sharedInstance.sessionDataObjectContainer[curSessName]?.isFinalized)!
    {
        setupMySession(isLive: false, isFinalized: true)
    }
    else
    {
        setupMySession(isLive: true, isFinalized: false)
        var fromTempChoose = ShareData.sharedInstance.startingSessionFromTempChoose && !(ShareData.sharedInstance.globalsVar?.hasStartedSession)!

        if fromTempChoose || (ShareData.sharedInstance.resumingSessionFromSessDet && !(ShareData.sharedInstance.globalsVar?.hasResumedSession)!)
        {
            let mySessionView = getSessionView()
            mySessionView.curScene.pauseSession(isStartingNow: true)
            blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
            //}
            blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            //always fill the view
            blurEffectView?.frame = self.view.bounds
            blurEffectView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView!)
        }
...
}
    var mySessObj = getSessionView() //these three lines of code were added to try to fix the problem.  They weren't in the original code
    mySessObj.frame = self.view.bounds
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
 ...

func setupMySession(isLive: Bool, isFinalized: Bool)
{
    let mySessionView = getSessionView()
    //mySessionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mySessionView.delegate = self
    sessionNameIndex = self.getSessionNumber() - 1

    let myName = ShareData.sharedInstance.currentAccount.name
    var curSessName = generateCurrentAccountName(name: myName!, value: self.getSessionNumber())
    //var names = generateAllPossibleSessionNames(name: myName!)
    let curSession = ShareData.sharedInstance.sessionDataObjectContainer[curSessName]

    mySessionView.onView(index: getSessionNumber(), sessionName: curSessName, isLive: isLive, isFinalized: isFinalized)
    if isLive
    {
        let val = curSession?.currentValue()
        mySessionView.curScene.setStartPosition(newValue: val!) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding your custom view programatically? If so, can you share the code where you do that?

Comment: The view is not added programmatically. It's an IBOutlet.

Comment: I have recreated your constraints and in my opinion, they are not the best set of constraints. It's no wonder that you are seeing weird behaviour. I would suggest that you first draw out the sketch on a piece of paper and then start assigning constraints in a logical manner. For example, you should look into making your buttons a subview of Scroll Control Image and set their constraints relative to this view instead of haphazard constraints that vaguely conform the UI to your desired version. Remember, what you see on storyboard might not be exactly what you see when the app is running

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to examine my constraints.  I appreciate that you are trying to help.  I think that some of the constraints you saw were constraints generated by "Reset to Suggested Constraints", which did create some fairly strange constraints.  I have changed the constraints to be more... sane constraints, and I have added a picture of the new constraints to this page.  Your complaint that it might help making the buttons a subview of the Scroll Control Image- as best as I can tell, in order to do that I would have to create a custom UIView, correct?

Comment: I do think that making a custom uiview just so the constraints of the buttons could be made to the scroll control image seems like a bit much.  I guess I'm skeptical that that will make a difference, although I may try the view without the buttons- the buttons are only there as an additional option for changing pages besides swiping.  Is it possible that the code inside the custom SKView could be the problem?  Also, I used "Inferred" instead of "Freeform" because the size of the view should be based on the size of the parent view.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you show any code you have that interacts with the `IBOutlet`?

Comment: That is basically all the code that interacts with the `IBOutlet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me awhile to figure this one out.  The software was adding an auto resizing mask constraint to the view, which was causing it to look funny.  In order to fix this problem, in the initialization of the custom UIView, I had to add the following lines of code:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
self.view.frame = self.bounds
```

I guess the software treats the class that is the custom UIView and the view inside it that holds everything as two separate views.  I wish the tutorials I found online about creating a custom UIView had included that we need to set the auto resizing mask and the view's frame, but oh well.  Lesson learned.